# Obtener la extensión de un nombre de archivo con PHP

Tags: php

tengo esta consulta:

```
$nombre_archivo = niidea.jpg;
$extension = explode(".", $nombre_archivo);
echo $extension[1]
```

Resultado: jpg

Necesito leer los ultimos 3 o 4 según el caso después del punto, puede darse el caso de lo siguientes ejemplo:

```
echo $nombre_archivo = niidea.jpg; // debe leer jpg
echo $nombre_archivo = niidea.xls; // debe leer xls
echo $nombre_archivo = niidea.xlsx; // debe leer xlsx
echo $nombre_archivo = niidea.doc; // debe leer doc
echo $nombre_archivo = niidea.docx; // debe leer docx
```

consideremos que puede existir uno o mas puntos entre los nombres de los archivos antes de su extension:

```
echo $nombre_archivo = ni.idea.xls; // debe leer xls
echo $nombre_archivo = ni.idea.xlsx; // debe leer xlsx
echo $nombre_archivo = ni..idea.doc; // debe leer doc
echo $nombre_archivo = ni...idea.docx; // debe leer docx
```

Si lograse leer solamente los 3 o 4 últimos dígitos ya no me importaría lo que tenga escrito a la izquierda.

Comment: entonces deberiamos quitar la etiqueta mysql no? dos ideas.. si php tiene un split por . <- te quedas con el ultimo item del array.. y si no, https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strrpos.php para ubicar el ultimo punto.. y usar eso para substr ;)

Comment: Por favor, entrecomilla los nombres de archivo, son cadenas en PHP ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplemente coge los caracteres a partir del último punto.

Fíjate en la siguiente función que sirve para obtener la extensión.
Con strrpos() se busca la posición del último punto.
Si el nombre de archivo está vacío, o no tiene punto, se devuelve cadena vacía.
En caso contrario, se devuelve la cadena a partir del punto (excluyéndolo).
Opcionalmente, se pone en minúsculas.

```
/**
 * @return string
 * @param $file string
 * @param $tolower bool
 * @desc Gets the extension of a given file, in lowercase if $tolower
 */
function getExtension($file, $tolower=true)
{
    $file = basename($file);
    $pos = strrpos($file, '.');

    if ($file == '' || $pos === false) {
        return '';
    }

    $extension = substr($file, $pos+1);
    if ($tolower) {
        $extension = strtolower($extension);
    }

    return $extension;
}
```